# I/O errors on pendrive - what may cause them? (maybe a bad sector)

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04, bad-sectors

When I use a pendrive with Ubuntu, it sometimes disconnects. I looked in syslog and I found `I/O error, dev sdb, sector 31159048`, so I suppose it's a bad sector. How can I fix it?

Here's a full log of what happens:

```
Dec 12 09:14:04 puff kernel: [18790.617487] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
... and after a while, during a file transfer:
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.708328] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 9
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.718691] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.718707] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.718709] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 01 db 73 08 00 00 f0 00
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.718714] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 31159048
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.719247] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.719249] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.719250] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 01 db 73 f8 00 00 f0 00
Dec 12 09:15:34 puff kernel: [18880.719254] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 31159288
Dec 12 09:15:35 puff kernel: [18881.010913] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
Dec 12 09:15:35 puff kernel: [18881.205915] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
Dec 12 09:15:35 puff mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
Dec 12 09:15:35 puff mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.039242] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JetFlash Transcend 16GB   1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.040027] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.040601] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 31703040 512-byte logical blocks: (16.2 GB/15.1 GiB)
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.042215] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.042219] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.042934] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.042938] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.045835] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.045838] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.046834]  sdb: sdb1
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.049582] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.049587] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Dec 12 09:15:37 puff kernel: [18883.049591] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bad sector, the only way to fix it is to get a new pen drive. It's also possible that the drive connector is bad, in which case you also need a new drive. A third possibility is that the port on your computer is bad, did you try another port? **If it's broken on one port, that port is broken. If the drive is broken on more then one PC then the drive is broken.**